# Cordova (Android). AppRate plugin simply brings up blank screen

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, rate

I am trying to get the app rate plugin working for Visual Studio Cordova project and I can not see to get it working (for Android device).

I basically have a button that when clicked calls a method in my javascript file called RateTheApp.

My code is below.  I basically copied/used the code from: https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate

When the I call my RateTheApp routine the screen on the device goes blank and nothing happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Ted

```
AppRate.preferences = {
   useLanguage: 'en',
   openStoreInApp: true,
   displayAppName: 'Here I Am',
   usesUntilPrompt: 5,
   promptAgainForEachNewVersion: false,
   storeAppURL: {
       ios: '<my_app_id>',
       android: 'market://details?id=com.tedjyoung.hereiam',
       windows: 'ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=<the apps Store ID>',
       blackberry: 'appworld://content/[App Id]/',
       windows8: 'ms-windows-store:Review?name=<the Package Family Name of the application>'
   },
   customLocale: {
       title: "Rate 'Here I Am'",
       message: "If you enjoy using 'Here I Am', would you mind taking a moment to rate it? It won’t take more than a minute. Thanks for your support!",
       cancelButtonLabel: "No, Thanks",
       laterButtonLabel: "Remind Me Later",
       rateButtonLabel: "Rate It Now"
   }
};

AppRate.preferences = {
   useCustomRateDialog: true,
   callbacks: {
       onRateDialogShow: function (callback) {
           callback(1) // cause immediate click on 'Rate Now' button 
       },
       onButtonClicked: function (buttonIndex) {
           console.log("onButtonClicked -> " + buttonIndex);
       }
   }
};

function RateTheApp() {
   try {
       AppRate.promptForRating(false);
   } catch (e) {
       alert("Error rating app.  Error = " + e.message);
   }
}
```

Comment: any exceptions in console? white blank screen usually means that you have errors

Answer (score 0):

Yes it may happen due to following reasons:-

1) You are not giving application url

2) you are not giving correct app url (package name or App id)

3) App is not available on play store or iTune

**Solution**

- first make sure that app is available on play store or iTune
- Place correct app Id and package name as mention in config.xml
- make sure that app base url is correct.